# Adding custom static block in footer issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I tried to add some static blocks in the footer: `<referenceContainer name="footer-container"` from xml and it's not working.

But if I add in: `<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">` after `name="absolute_footer"` it's working.

This is my code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="basket_rent">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">basket_rent</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="absolute_footer" template="html/absolute_footer.phtml" />
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="basket_rent">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">basket_rent</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

My block's identifier is: **basket_rent**.

Please Help and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to **extend** the default.xml file in your theme, add in the  a reference for the footer container and the script for the cms block.

Like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="basket_rent">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">basket_rent</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can also try to add after="-" in the cms script, it force to place this block at the end of the container.

Like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="basket_rent" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">basket_rent</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**PS: if you edit the core files of M2 maybe you have to clean the cache or upgrade the M2 setup. It's better to extend the file instead.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want add static block in footer, use below reference for it.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="basket_rent">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">basket_rent</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Will that work also if he will added it the same static block in the absolute_footer? Cuz from his post i see that he wants to add 2 static blocks in 2 different places